# A call to system() doesn't create a parent-child relation between my processes in Windows

Tags: windows, perl, process, windows-services

I'm using Perl to create a Windows service. I'm using `Win32::Daemon` for this purpose.

The Perl script that is handling the service (accepting start and stop callback, etc) uses the `system()` command to call a .bat file, that eventually call my final Perl program.

The issue is that when I stop the service, the process launched by `system()` is not closed, and neither are the final processes (launched by the one generated by `system()`).

It's like there is no "parent-child" relation between the processes (stopping the Windows service normally causes all related processes to be closed at the same time).

edit: I added the code above. I just displayed the main function that regiter the services callback and call StartService, and the three main callbacks : start, running, stop.

```
sub main {
        #registering service callbacks
        Win32::Daemon::RegisterCallbacks( {
            start       =>  \&Callback_Start,
            running     =>  \&Callback_Running,
            stop        =>  \&Callback_Stop,
            pause       =>  \&Callback_Pause,
            continue    =>  \&Callback_Continue,
         } );
        my %Context = (
            last_state => SERVICE_STOPPED,
            start_time => time(),
      );

      Win32::Daemon::StartService( \%Context, 2000 );

      # Here the service has stopped
      close STDERR; close STDOUT;
}


#function called after the start one
sub Callback_Running
{
   my( $Event, $Context ) = @_;

#Here I had to make an infinite loop to make the service "persistant". Otherwise it stops automatically (maybe there's something important I missed here?

   if( SERVICE_RUNNING == Win32::Daemon::State() )
   {
       Win32::Daemon::State( SERVICE_RUNNING );

   }
}   

#function first called by StartService
sub Callback_Start
{

#above is stated the system() call where I trigger the .bat script

       my( $Event, $Context ) = @_;

        my $cmd = "START \"\" /Dc:\\path\\to\\script\\dir\\ \"script.bat\"";

    print $cmd."\n";
    system($cmd);

   $Context->{last_state} = SERVICE_RUNNING;
   Win32::Daemon::State( SERVICE_RUNNING );
}

sub Callback_Stop
{
   my( $Event, $Context ) = @_;

   #Things I should do to stop the service, like closing the generated processes (if I knew their pid)

   $Context->{last_state} = SERVICE_STOPPED;
   Win32::Daemon::State( SERVICE_STOPPED );

   # We need to notify the Daemon that we want to stop callbacks and the service.
   Win32::Daemon::StopService();
}
```

Comment: [Add code](http://sscce.org/) to [exhibit the problem](http://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/~sgtatham/bugs#showmehow).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Windows, there are no parent-child relationships between processes.  Windows treats all processes as peers, and in particular killing a "parent" never kills the "child".

When a service receives a request to stop, it is responsible for closing/killing any processes it may have have created, if it is appropriate to do so.

You say that "stoping [sic] the windows service normally cause all related processes to be closed" but this is not usually the case; perhaps Win32::Daemon is doing this for you, but of course it has no way to know about any processes that are launched from your batch file.

The proper solution, if at all possible, is to implement your service in a single process.  Since in this case both processes are written in Perl, it should be relatively straightforward to combine them into a single program.

Comment: Ok, I thought it windows was acting like linux when a process creates other processes. I think the implementation of the overall scripts in one and only process is not possible, because the StartService function expect a return to be properly ended. If not, the service is "blocked" and can't process anymore callback.

Comment: Yes it does. There is two modules implementing the threads, but from what I heard both of them are not really robust. I'm going to give them a try. I will update this question with my result and mark your answer as resolving one if it does the trick. At the same time I will post the way I used to solve the problem. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Ok, after a long time I came back to the task and managed to not go through a .bat file to run my program. However, as my program is meant to run without real ending (it is a http server), I have issues entering the "Stop" callback. But your answer lead me to a good reach and resolved the initial question.

Answer (score 2):

Harry Johnston's answer is basically correct.  One thing that you can do, if keeping track of the "children" is difficult, is to place all of the processes that you create into a [Windows Job](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms684161%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) object instead of launching them via `system`, and then kill the job in your process's service shutdown code.

I'm not sure how easy that is to do from Perl, but it isn't too difficult from C.  It does look like there are a few CPAN modules that would help you with this, such as [Win32::Job](http://search.cpan.org/~jdb/Win32-Job-0.04/Job.pm) and [Win32::JobAdd](http://search.cpan.org/~djoos/Win32-JobAdd-1.00/lib/Win32/JobAdd.pm), but I don't have any experience with them myself.

Comment: I'm going to have a look tomorow, this seems an interesting solution if I can't retrieve easily the pid of my generated processes. Implementing the process in one single thread could be a better solution, but at the moment I couldn't find a way to do it (see my coment to Harry's answer)

Comment: Well you could spawn another thread in the same process, or perhaps just spawn a new process and run everything in that one other process and just keep track of that one pid, if that is possible in your design.

Answer (score 1):

If the batch file terminates before your final Perl program, then the final Perl program will have no parent because its parent (the batch file's command processor (like cmd.exe)) died.

*(updated to include a specific scenario where this could happen)*

One scenario:

1. Batch file B launches Perl program P1.
2. Perl program P1 launches Perl program PFINAL.
3. Perl program P1 terminates without waiting for PFINAL to terminate.
4. Batch file B moves on to the next command because P1 terminated.
5. If Batch file B then terminates before PFINAL terminates, then PFINAL is left parent-less, as both its parent (Perl program P1) and its grandparent (Batch file B) have terminated.

A common idiom when creating a daemon is to fork, then having the parent die so that the child (the actual daemon process) is left parent-less. This avoids problems with the daemon process still being connected with a controlling terminal.

Comment: What makes you think so? `cmd` will wait for `perl` to exit before executing the next statement of the batch file (or exiting, if it's the last statement).

Comment: But cmd is waiting for P1, not PFINAL. If P1 terminates before PFINAL, then cmd (Batch file B) will continue onto the next statement anyway and PFINAL loses its parent process.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem.

My perl script calls java application and after same time application should be killed.

I used `Win32::Process` module

```
Win32::Process::Create($ProcessObj,
    "C:/Java/bin/java.exe",
    "java.exe -cp bin/blablabla.jar",
    0,
    CREATE_NEW_CONSOLE,
    ".")

$ProcessObj->GetExitCode($retCode);         
$ProcessObj->Kill($retCode);
```

Hope this can help

Comment: This module seems usefull but I will first look upon the fork() command to manage a simultenaous thread.